# I can't make flexbox center the items using flexbox tools, but can using text-align. Why?

Tags: css, flexbox

I would really appreciate some help.

I have a very simple site. On that simple site I have a gallery of pictures, built with flexbox for a mobile view.

It looks like this:

```css
.photos {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 2%;
  background-color: #A5966D;
}

.library {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#image {
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 500px;
}

.library>a:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="photos">
    <div class="changing_photo">
      <img id=image src="img/all_pack.jpg" alt="all our dogs and me">
    </div>
    <div class="library">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/all_pack.jpg" alt="all our dogs and me" onclick='showPic(this)'></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="img/daffy_1.jpg" alt="Daffy in neon lights" onclick='showPic(this)'></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="img/daffy_2.jpg" alt="Daffy being cute" onclick='showPic(this)'></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="img/daffy_collage.jpg" alt="collage of photos of Daffy" onclick='showPic(this)'></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="img/daffy_doki_sleep.jpg" alt="Daffy and Dokki sleeping" onclick='showPic(this)'></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="img/doki_1.jpg" alt="Doki in the forest" onclick='showPic(this)'></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="img/doki_2.jpg" alt="Doki under the table" onclick='showPic(this)'></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="img/doki_collage.jpg" alt="collage of photos of Dokki" onclick='showPic(this)'></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="img/watching_food.jpg" alt="pets watching human cook" onclick='showPic(this)'></a>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Problem is that I can not make pictures in .library to be centered using these three:

```
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
align-content: center;
```

The only way pictures would become centered is if I use `text-align: center;`, which seems to be wrong, cause it should be achievable just with flexbox own tools.

Am I thinking wrong? In that case where am I thinking wrong?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `display:flex;` then you can use this property `align-items` and `justify content`. Otherwise `text-align: center;` is right

Comment: Those properties do not work for me unfortunately, and I am trying to understand why.

Comment: could you please show me the output and what do you want ?

Comment: I want to be able to regulate the position of children inside my flexbox with the properties that come with flexbox, not the text-align that is made to align text. I don't understand why align-items and justify-content don't work.